# Задача на событие мыши js

Tags: javascript

Есть код

```js
let balance = 0;
[...document.querySelectorAll(".itemAdd")].forEach(item => {
  
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let sum = document.querySelector(".item_price").textContent;
    sum = parseInt(sum.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""),);
    balance = balance + sum;
    alert("balance = " + balance);
    localStorage.setItem("balance" , JSON.stringify(balance))

document.getElementById('purse').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('balance');


   if (balance > 0){
    document.getElementById('empty_card').hidden = true;
  };
 
    
    
  });
});
```

```html
<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"></a><i class="itemAdd"></i></a><span class="item_price"> 310</span></h4>
```

но при добавление этого кода

```js
document.getElementById('hider').onclick = function() {
    alert(balance / 2);  
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="hider" value="поделить balance на 2"/>
```

код выше перестаёт работать.Можете помочь пофиксить или исправить ну или хотяб обяснить почему оно не работает буду благодарен

Comment: ещё никогда не задавал здесь вопросы поэтому извиняюсь если все плохо изложил

Comment: Выложите код полностью, как вы добавляете код с alert и тот что уже выложили

Comment: `function() { alert(balance / 2);` о_О а скобку кто будет закрывать? `function() { alert(balance / 2); };`